# How to configure a Visual Studio 2022 solution to compile the same code to .NET 4.8 and .NET 7?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-4.8, .net-7.0

### Problem description

I have a solution based on .NET Framework 4.8, it is a class library project written with VB.NET, built with VS2019 and updated to VS2022.

The project is VERY heavy (a full toolset for .NET developers), thousands of classes, millions of lines of code, etc.

I would like to upgrade this solution to .NET Core 7, but the [Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) is a pain to do to this, I just can't do it in this way due all the compiler errors I get. Anyways, I managed to prune "non-essential" code from the solution generated by the upgrade assistant and fix all compiler errors to be able at least compile the "core" of the code in .NET 7.

However, I have found that this workaround is also quite unfeasible, first because it is missing a lot of code and features from the solution based on .NET FW 4.8, and secondly because I make changes and updates to the solution based on .NET FW 4.8, and then have to copy and adapt these changes and updates to the .NET 7 solution. It is a nightmare for one single person.

---

### Conclusions

So I've come to the conclusion that the best option is to create/start a single Visual Studio solution from scratch, in VS2002, a .NET 7 solution configured in such a way that the code can be compiled to build .NET FW 4.8 dlls and .NET 7 dlls, and then "just" I have to gradually copy and adapt the code from the original solution based on .NET FW 4.8, to this new empty solution to make the code compatible with .NET FW 4.8 and .NET 7. And once I finish I can delete forever the solution based on .NET FW 4.8.

I hope you are understanding me correctly at this point.

---

### Question

And what is the problem I have about all what I have exposed above?.

Well, the main problem (aside from the fact that my experience with .NET Core is minimal) is that I'm not very clear on how to do this kind of solution. Or if it can be done.

That is, a .NET 7 solution, with a single class library project, whose configuration is made to compile the code to build .NET FW 4.8 dlls in one directory, and another configuration to compile the same code to build the respective .NET 7 dlls in another directory.

Logically I think I'll need to use [Conditional Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/conditional-compilation) so that incompatible code doesn't compile to build the .NET 7 dlls, but beyond that I don't quite know how to create the necessary solution configuration.

I guess the question could be summarized as follows:

**How to configure a Visual Studio 2022 solution to compile the same code to .NET 4.8 and .NET 7?**

I need guidance, advice or examples to start carrying this out.

EDIT:

I just would like to have a single .NET 7 solution on which I can compile the same code to generate dlls for .NET 4.8 (that can be imported in .NET Framework projects) and dlls for .NET 7 (that can be imported in .NET 7 projects), sharing the same code (filtered with conditional compilation), all within the same .NET 7 project / solution.

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand, 4.8 and 7 are not compatible between. One can't read another one DLL. I don't see a solution to this instead making two differents projects.

Comment: Well, technically, .NET 7 can use .NET 4.8 DLLs. However, if the one uses features that the other doesn't have, you get runtime errors. Apart from that, migrating a large scale non-trivial solution is hard work that requires lots of planning and a good migration plan. Personally, having been in such a situation, I have migrated one project after the other, (basically along the dependency tree). You basically must work with a source control system and a separate "branch" to keep your work separate for long enough but stay up to date with the .NET 4.8 code, which might evolve in the meantime.

Comment: @Leandro Bardelli Thanks for comment. As you know many code written in 4.8 works with 7.0 (those who share same namespaces, same member names and same parameters), the incompatible code I could figure to exclude or adapt it for .NET 7 with conditional compilation. I just would like to compile the same code to generate dlls for .NET 4.8 (that can be imported in .NET Framework projects) and dlls for .NET 7 (that can be imported in .NET 7 projects), sharing the same code (filtered with conditional compilation), all within the same project / solution.

Comment: Of course you can do it, you can targeting another framework but if the app is important, you will find some troubles in the COM communications between DLL or in the runtime processing and I would not recommend this as is not a good solution.

Comment: How can I target .NET Framework 4.8 from a .NET 7 project?, I think the project properties doesn't brings this "porting" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to configure a Visual Studio 2022 solution to compile the same code to .NET 4.8 and .NET 7?

There are two main options, the multitargeting + conditional compilation, which you have already (almost) discovered. I was not able to find guidance for VB, but here are docs for C#, maybe they can give you some directions:

- [Support multiple .NET Framework versions in your project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file)
- [MSBuild multitargeting overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-multitargeting-overview?view=vs-2022)
- [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks)

Second option which can be considered - using [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0):

> .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are available on multiple .NET implementations. The motivation behind .NET Standard was to establish greater uniformity in the .NET ecosystem. .NET 5 and later versions adopt a different approach to establishing uniformity that eliminates the need for .NET Standard in most scenarios. However, if you want to share code between .NET Framework and any other .NET implementation, such as .NET Core, your library should target .NET Standard 2.0. No new versions of .NET Standard will be released, but .NET 5, .NET 6, and all future versions will continue to support .NET Standard 2.1 and earlier.

So you can move your shared code to .NET Standard library (.NET Standard 2.0 is latest supported by .NET Framework) and this library can be referenced by both .NET (Core) and .NET Framework target projects. Though this option will not be suitable for all kind of libraries, .NET Standard APIs are vast but still quite limited.

Comment: .NET Standard is not being updated. It might be a stepping stone towards your migration, but not an end state. In future you'll want to use bits that aren't available in .NET Standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT really do this ASSUMING this is a web forms application.

If this is a MVC application, then you can probably convert and run as .NET Core without any much changes.

So, the FIRST answer here is if the project is a webforms project, or if this is a MVC web project?

So, just keep in mind that there is ZERO support for webforms projects using .NET Core. You can't use or have webforms run as .NET Core right now, and they MUST be .NET Framework, not .NET Core framework.

As noted, if this is a MVC project, then you can use .NET Core, and next to none code changes would be required - with few exceptions.

But, if this is webforms, then you can't choose .NET Core or .NET Framework. (you must use .NET Framework)

In theory, mvc projects could be based on .NET Core or .NET Framework, but with your given information, this looks to be a webforms project, and not a mvc one, so that being the case, no, you can't do this.

So, keep in mind that MVC projects are vast different. The difference betwene a MVC project in .NET Core, or a MVC project in .NET Core? You probably can't tell the difference.

however, webforms vs MVC projects? Now that is a WHOLE different ballgame and matter.  Webform projects can't be converted to MVC projects without a whole re-write of that applcation.

And if the project is a MVC project already? Then I doubt VERY much that one would care or even notice the difference if you using .NET Framework, or .NET Core. And your code behind will be really the same also with few exceptions between .NET Core and .NET frameworks.